# What am I doing wrong in solving $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (\cos (ax) - \sin (bx))^2\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

What am I doing wrong in solving $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (\cos (ax) - \sin (bx))^2\ dx$?

Here's my method:

> $$\begin{align}I &= \displaystyle\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (\cos (ax) - \sin (bx))^2\ dx = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (\cos (ax) + \sin (bx))^2\ dx\tag{$*$}
> \\&\implies 2I = 2\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos^2(ax) + \sin^2(bx) dx
> \\&\implies I = \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{1 + \cos(2ax)}{2} + \frac{1-\cos(2bx)}{2} dx
> \\&\implies I = x + \frac{\sin(2ax)}{4} - \frac{\sin(2bx)}{4}\bigg|_{-\pi}^\pi
> \\&\implies I = 2\pi\end{align}$$
> ... which is independent of $a$ and $b$.
> But this integral [does depend](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6gtwbnnrcp) on the value of $a$ and $b$.

What's wrong here?

---

$(*)$ Applied property $$\int_{a}^b f(x) dx = \int_a^b f(a + b - x) dx$$

Comment: It looks like perhaps you're thinking that $\sin(2a\pi)=\sin(2b\pi)=0$. That would be true if $a$ and $b$ were integers, but they're not integers...

Comment: Ohh yes @David my bad. Thanks. You may post it as an answer if you like. I'll definitely accept that.

Answer (score 1):

Note
$$ \int\cos(2ax)dx=\frac{1}{2a}\sin(2ax)+C. $$
Clearly you forgot coefficient.

Comment: OOPS! :P $ $ $ $

Comment: Actually that was a typing mistake. I wrote $\frac{\sin(2ax)}{2a}$ while solving in notebook. But missed it while typing. My question has been answered by 
David C. Ullrich.

Comment: Greet! We often forget something.